# A Riemannian metric on the diffeomorphism group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

The (smooth) diffeomorphism group of the unit circle can be defined as
$$\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)=\{\varphi\in C^\infty(S^1,S^1)\,|\,\varphi'>0\}.$$
Identify $S^1$ with the interval $[0,1]$ via $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},$ and consider the Lie subgroup $\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)$ of $\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)$ defined as
$$\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)=\{\varphi\in C^\infty(S^1,S^1)\,|\,\varphi'>0,\,\varphi(0)=0\}.$$
Both of these groups are infinite-dimensional Lie groups, and we can equip $\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)$ with the Riemannian metric
$$G_{\varphi}(X,Y)=\int_{S^1}\frac{X'Y'}{\varphi'}d\theta$$
for $\varphi \in \operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)$ and $X,Y \in T_{\varphi}\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1),$ where the tangent space consists of smooth vector fields on $S^1$ $\textit{along $\varphi$}.$ Since we're in dimension one, we just identify a vector field with it's component function and treat $X,Y$ as real-valued functions on $S^1=[0,1],$ not vector fields acting on one another.
$\textit{Supposedly,}$ the condition $\varphi(0)=0$ (or one similar in effect) is required to ensure that $G_{\varphi}(X,Y)$ is in fact a Riemannian metric, i.e that it defines an inner product on each of the tangent spaces. But bilinearity, symmetry, and positive-definiteness of $G_{\varphi}(X,Y)$ all seem to obviously be satisfied, independent of the values taken on by $\varphi$. Am I missing something? Do we really need $\varphi(0)=0$ to ensure $G$ is a Riemannian metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory of infinite dimensional Lie groups is rather involved, so these comments may be somewhat imprecise.

Let $\mathfrak{X}S^1$ denote the space of smooth vector fields on $S^1$ and $\mathfrak{X}_0S^1\subset\mathfrak{X}S^1$ denote the set of vector fields which vanish at $0\in S^1$. $\mathfrak{X}S^1$ is the Lie algbebra of $\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)$, while $\mathfrak{X}_0S^1$ is the Lie algbebra of $\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)$ (since the flow of a vector field $X$ fixes $0$ iff $X(0)=0$). The inner product you propose is in fact *not* positive definite on $\mathfrak{X}S^1$, since $G_{\operatorname{id}}(X,X)=0$ for any constant vector field $X$. It is, however, positive definite on $\mathfrak{X}_0S^1$.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. Could you please elaborate a bit on your remark about the flow? Why does the Lie algebra of $\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)$ consist of vector fields that vanish at $0\in S^1$, and how does requiring $\varphi(0)=0$ give rise to this?

Comment: @Stuck In this context, the exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{X}S^1\to\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)$ is defined by$$\exp(tX)(\theta)=\Phi_X(t,\theta)$$where $\Phi_X:\mathbb{R}\times S^1\to S^1$ is the flow of $X$. If $X\in\operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1))$, It should certainly satisfy $\exp(tX)\in\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So for all $X\in\mathfrak{X}_0S^1,$ $\operatorname{exp}(tX)\in\operatorname{Diff}_0S^1,$ and hence $\operatorname{exp}(tX)(0)=\Phi_X(t,0)=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R},$ by definition of $\operatorname{Diff}_0S^1.$ And by definition of the flow, this means $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_X(t,0)=X(\Phi_X(t,0))=X(0)=0,$ correct? I'm pretty new to this stuff and just want to make sure..

Comment: @Stuck Yes, exactly. This shows that $\exp(tX)\in\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)\implies X(0)=0$. In fact the implication goes both ways $\exp(tX)\in\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)\iff X(0)=0$ by a similar argument, so the Lie algebra of $\operatorname{Diff}_0(S^1)$ is exactly $\mathfrak{X}_0S^1$. (Provided we define the Lie algebra as the set of vector fields whose flows lie in the corresponding subgroup.)

Comment: I have one follow up clarification. The exponential map gives a one-parameter subgroup $\gamma_X(t)$, which is just an integral curve (that's also a homomorphism) of the vector field $X$, but in this context, the integral curve is on $\operatorname{Diff}(S^1),$ so it looks like $\gamma_X(t)(\theta),$ which we can essentially think of as a flow because it depends on a point $\theta\in S^1$? Is this correct or am I missing something? Basically I'm trying to make sure I understand exactly why the exponential map is equal to a flow in this scenario.

Comment: @Stuck Yes, note that fixing $t$ in the flow gives a diffeomorphism $x\mapsto\Phi_X(t,x)$, so we can think of the partial evaluation of the flow as a map $\mathbb{R}\to\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)$, which we can call the one-parameter subgroup generated by $X$.

Comment: Since $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ is *not* a Lie group by most definitions, it is perhaps best to regard this formulation as an *analogy*, taking as a starting point that $\mathfrak{X}M\xrightarrow{\exp}\operatorname{Diff}(M)$, defined in terms of flows, shares many properties with $\mathfrak{g}\xrightarrow{\exp}G$ for a finite-dimensional Lie group $G$. In order to say rigorously that $\mathfrak{X}M$ *is* the Lie algebra of $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ and $\exp$ *is* the exponential map, one must first formulate a theory of infinite-dimensional Fréchet Lie groups, which is not a trivial task.

Comment: @ Kajelad Thanks, very much. I don't (yet) understand the details, but I have seen $\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)$ referred to as an infinite-dimensional Lie group, more than once. Is this not technically the case? Was it just the authors speaking loosely (i.e. they're $\textit{kinda}$ like Lie groups)? If you have any references that helped you understand this stuff, I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @Stuck A Lie group is by definition a smooth manifold, which is by definition finite-dimensional. In order to define an infinite-dimensional generalization of Lie groups, one must first have an infinite-dimensional generalization of manifolds. There are many inequivalent ways of doing this, each with its own subtleties. As a result, infinite-dimensional Lie groups are a broad field, and one about which I know very little. If you want to look into it, [this paper](https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00391789/document) provides a decent overview, and plenty of citations.

Comment: Still, some of the basic properties of $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ can be understood from the analogy perspective (with much less functional analysis involved), you just need to be aware that results from the finite-dimensional theory won't always apply.

Comment: Yes the definition I have seen for infinite-dimensional manifolds is directly analogous to the definition for finite-dimensions except instead of charts being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, the charts are homeomorphic to some arbitrary (possibly infinite-dimensional) topological vector space. This seems to me the most natural way to define it. I didn't know there were many inequivalent ways of doing this. You seem to know a decent amount about them to me! Ha. I appreciate the reference, and thanks very much for your time during this little discussion.